# php: Select statement is throwing an error only in Linux Mint

Tags: php, mysql

I have assigned a variable

```
$car = $variable; // $variable gets a value from post method and it is an integer.
```

I have written a select statement:

```
$sql ="SELECT data FROM thisTable WHERE value='$car'";
```

I wrote this code in Windows and it was working fine.
I tried to execute the same in lampp in LinuxMint and it thows the error

> Trying to get property of non-object.

I'm learning PHP so not sure about the error, can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: would you please post all the code corresponding with you question.

Comment: Your problem is not in your query, there is at another place, post full code please

Comment: Linux is case sensitive where windows is not.   (check your table name should also be thisTable)

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Thanks Man, the problem was case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below documentation link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html